# Advantage of using shared instances in database connection class

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, static

In many codes I have seen classes (that imports FMDatabase) that contains methods for creating a database connection, adding or removing value from data from database.. I found a shared instance method to create a shared instance of our class. What are it's advantages? I know one thing that each time you create a new connection there will be a time delay. We can avoid it using shared instance. But, are there any more reasons for using shared instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping only one connection to database give you an unique point where you can read or write on your database (enqueuing all disk operation here) avoiding a lot of problems about handling reads and writes in different places of your application.